# Creating encodings for characters stored in leaves in a Huffman Tree

Tags: java, encoding, binary-tree, huffman-code

I am trying to traverse my Huffman Tree that I've created and create binary 'encodings' for each character input, which are stored in the leaves of my tree. How I am doing this is recursively traversing the tree, and once I reach a leaf I am storing the encoding into the respective array index for the int value of the character. For example, the binary encoding for character 'A' would be stored in index 65. How the encodings are built is every time we go to the left, we append 0 to the string encoding, and every time we go right we append 1 to the string encoding. Also, as a side note, non-leaf nodes are holding the character with value 128, and we are only expecting character values 0-127 in the leaves. For a visual representation, here is an example of what I mean: [HuffmanTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tnun.png)

My current attempt at this is definitely heading in the right direction, but I haven't really been able to figure out why I am getting the result I am.

```
private String[] pathsToLeaves(Node r) {
    String[] array = new String[128];
    String s = "";
    String[] toReturn = pathsToLeaves(r, array, s);
    return toReturn;
}

private String[] pathsToLeaves(Node r, String[] array, String s) {
    if(r.data != (char)128) {
        array[r.data] = s;
    } else {
        if(r.left != null) {
            s += "0";
            pathsToLeaves(r.left, array, s);
        } else if(r.right != null) {
            s += "1";
            pathsToLeaves(r.right, array, s);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

What is happening in the array that is returned is completely null, with just one index holding the encoding '000'. I suspect that I need some way to return to the beginning of my tree after creating an encoding in my first if statement, but then that begs the question as to how one ensures that the same path is not followed again?

My end all be all question: How can I ensure that I return to the top of my tree after storing an encoding, while also making sure that I do not follow a path I've already been on?

Comment: Your recursive `pathsToLeaves` calls are ignoring the result that is returned - you probably want `array = pathsToLeaves(r.left, array, s);` (this is for the left child).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Using this advice I was able to get it to work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With some help from 500 - Internal Server Error's comment, I was able to modify my current code and get it to work! Here it is for those curious:

```
private String[] pathsToLeaves(Node r, String[] array, String s) {
    if(r.left == null && r.right == null) {
        array[r.data] = s;
        } else {
            array = pathsToLeaves(r.left, array, s + "0");
            array = pathsToLeaves(r.right, array, s + "1");
        }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. I noticed you're a new poster and just wanted to give a quick tip; it's useful in an answer (particularly one that involves modifying the code) to add a brief note saying how you resolved the issue. e.g., in this case: "I made sure to use the return value of the recursive function call, by setting array equal to it."